# Android customView how to calculate onMeasure to fill parent

Tags: android, android-view

I'm trying to draw a custom view, everything is rendering fine, except the right most portion is cut off.   I want the view to fill the parent and only use the needed amount of height (i.e the height of the bitmap I'm drawing. When i remove padding from the xml layout of the activity the custom view renders fine.  So I'm not calculating onMeasure with the parents padding taken into account.

Please could someone take a look at this code and describe why and how I am going wrong?  Thanks

EDITED TO include @nicko's answer and more detail:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);

    ViewParent parent = getParent();
    int leftPadding = 0;
    int rightPadding = 0;

    if (parent instanceof ViewGroup) {
        leftPadding = ((ViewGroup) parent).getPaddingLeft();
        rightPadding = ((ViewGroup) parent).getPaddingRight();
    }
    float wanabeHeight = calendar.getHeight();
    float wanabeWidth = parentWidth - leftPadding - rightPadding;

    int height = 0;
    //Determine Height
    switch(heightMode){
        case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY: height = parentHeight;
            break;
        case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            height = Math.min((int)wanabeHeight, parentHeight);
            break;
        case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        default:
            height = (int)wanabeHeight;
            break;
    }
    setMeasuredDimension((int)wanabeWidth, height);
}


@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    calendarX = left;
    personX = (int)((right - left) * 0.5);
    checkX = right - check.getWidth() - getPaddingRight();
    lineY = (int)((bottom - top) * 0.5);
    bitmapY = (int)(((bottom - top) * 0.5) - (calendar.getHeight() * 0.5));
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(calendar, calendarX, bitmapY, paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(person, personX, bitmapY, paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(check, checkX, bitmapY, paint);

    canvas.drawLine((calendarX + calendar.getWidth() + PADDING), lineY, personX - PADDING, lineY, linePaint);
    canvas.drawLine((personX + person.getWidth() + PADDING), lineY, checkX - PADDING, lineY, linePaint);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `onDraw`, everything is relative to the canvas - but it seems that you are drawing everything according to the view positions that come through in `onLayout` which are relative to the screen.

So, for your right hand image, you actually need to calculate the X position like this:

```
checkX = right - left - check.getWidth();
```

You'll also probably find that the left hand image is indented a bit if the parent has any padding so try positioning it at 0:

```
calendarX = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get parent padding following way:

```
ViewParent parent = getParent();
int topPadding = 0;
int bottomPadding = 0;

if (parent instanceof ViewGroup) {
    topPadding = ((ViewGroup) parent).getPaddingTop();
    bottomPadding = ((ViewGroup) parent).getPaddingBottom();
}
```

And use it:

```
parentHeight -= topPadding - bottomPadding;
int height = 0;

//Determine Height
switch(heightMode){
    case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY: 
        height = parentHeight;
        break;
    case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        height = Math.min((int)wanabeHeight, parentHeight);
        break;
    case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    default:
        height = (int)wanabeHeight; 
        break;
}
```

Comment: No need for "parent != null" check. Since it is trivially managed by instanceof operator.

Comment: Heya, I tried this however the right bitmap (check) is still cut off. I modified your answer to adjust the parent width rather than height (as its the right hand side being cut off).  I calculate checkX in onLayout() and draw the bitmap 'check' in onDraw.

Comment: Yes, you can get left and right padding with same approach and use them like height was used in my example code.

Comment: This solution did not fix the problem for me